# Hierarchical Black Box Variational Inference : Choice of inverse flow

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, variational-bayes

I am reading through [Black Box Variational Inference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0118.pdf), and having trouble understanding the section for hierarchical inference, where the normalizing flow is introduced. Should this be an arbitrary number of planar transformations, like introduced [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05770.pdf), or should these be selected on a model-specific basis?

The only working example I could find was in the [thesis](ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/reports/2017/008.pdf) (Section 5.3.2) the paper is written from, where the number of functions and form is selected, without any details.